# Angular/Javascript : Copy a simple number by value without reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, copy, deep-copy

I am trying to copy a simple scope variable containing an id without referencing it.

Here is a piece of code showing what I'm doing :

```
.controller('ctl', function($scope, $rootScope, Resource) {
    var controllerScope = this;

    this.tId = 1;

    /* ... */

    this.addProject = function() {
      this.supportedProjects.push(this.add.project);
      this.supportedProjects = this.supportedProjects.map(function(object) {
        var id = angular.copy(controllerScope.tId);

        if (object.title.title)
          return {
            id: id,
            title: object.title.title,
          };
        else
          return {
            id: id,
            title: object.title,
          };
      });
      this.tId++;
    /* ... */
    };
}
```

In that case, the objects in `supportedProjects` all contain the same id.
So what is the proper way to copy without reference ?

I don't have a clue of what's going on.

Edit : It was me doing things wrong with the `map` function.

Comment: Why are your running `this.supportedProjects` through a `map()` call that sets all the IDs to the same value? Is this the desired behavior? If not, what is?

Comment: It's just to reformat the object to have a proper `title`, there is probably a better way to do it though

Comment: But you are setting every objects ID to `controllerScope.tId`. Is this what you want to do? I don't really get the idea here.

Comment: Again, do you want to set all supported Projects to the same tId or not? What is the desired behavior here?

Comment: yea I think u r right, I probably used map the wrong way. I just wanted to change the title field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand what you are trying to do, but this should work:

```
this.supportedProjects = this.supportedProjects.map(function(object) {

    if (object.title.title)
      object.title = object.title.title;

    return object;
 });
```

Comment: Yea, like you said I missused map. The only thing missing after that is `this.add.project.id = this.tId;` before the `push(...)`

Comment: Great I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.controller('ctl', function($scope, $rootScope, Resource) {
    var controllerScope = this;

    this.tId = 0;

    /* ... */

    this.addProject = function() {
      this.supportedProjects.push(this.add.project);
      this.supportedProjects = this.supportedProjects.map(function(object) {
        var id = controllerScope.tId + 1;

        if (object.title.title)
          return {
            id: id,
            title: object.title.title,
          };
        else
          return {
            id: id,
            title: object.title,
          };
      });
      controllerScope.tId++;
    /* ... */
    };
}
```